# Django User Authentication - Can't pass @login_required decorator

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

So I'm currently trying to implement an already existing application for payment processing via Braintree (https://github.com/Tivix/django-braintree for reference). It seems like all the meat of this application is placed at the /payments-billing/ directory but I can't seem to get into it to check it out. It seems like what's stopping me is a @login_required decorator placed just before the view since whenever I access the directory it sends me back to the defined LOGIN_URL. However I have set up a login feature at the LOGIN_URL that authenticates the user and then sends them to /payments-billing/ but it just redirects back again. Here is my code:

```
username = form.cleaned_data['username']
password = form.cleaned_data['password']

user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    # Password verified for user
    if user.is_active:
       return redirect(self.success_url)
    else:
        return redirect('/')
else:
    return redirect('/')
```

Clearly the user is being authenticated and is active since it passes both tests when you try it, but it always just sends the user back to the LOGIN_URL rather than /payments-billing/. Anyone know what's the deal here?

Comment: Is your `user` instance active ? (You can verify that in the database or the admin interface)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `authenticate` function doesn't log a user in, it just checks their username/password. You also have to call `django.contrib.auth.login()` to do the actual logging in. See the example in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login).

Comment: Ah, I just didn't read far enough down onto the Django auth tutorial, haha. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
username = form.cleaned_data['username']
password = form.cleaned_data['password']

user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

login(request, user)  
### Now it should get redirected to  /payments-billing/

if user is not None:
    # Password verified for user
    if user.is_active:
       return redirect(self.success_url)
    else:
        return redirect('/')
else:
    return redirect('/')
```